# Does Akka onReceive method execute concurrently?

Tags: synchronization, actor, akka

Here is my scenario:

I have a master actor, which receives messages from multiple child actors. These messages contain data to be aggregated. In this aggregation logic, do I need to take care of synchronization issues, if I use a shared data structure to collect the aggregation?

```
else if(arg0 instanceof ReducedMsg){

                           ReducedMsg reduced = (ReducedMsg)arg0;
        counter.decrementAndGet();

        synchronized(finalResult){

            finalResult.add((KeyValue<K, V>) reduced.getReduced());

            if(counter.get() == 0){
                                    if(checkAndReduce(finalResult)){

                    finalResult.clear();
                }
                else{
                    stop();
                    latch.countDown();
                }

            }

        }



    }
```

So as you can see I have a finalResult, to which each message will be aggregated, and after a processing logic the collection needs to be cleared as well.

Actually what I am trying to implement is a recursive (associative) reduction mapreduce. So I need to keep the synchronized block I assume? Or is it by any chance Akka executes the onReceive one thread at a time?

This logic produces accurate and predictable result on small data set. My problem is when my input data set is a little large, the code hangs. I want to be sure that is because of the context switches for my synchronization block, so that I may dwelve into a different design.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`onReceive()` is **never** called concurrently. This is the most fundamental guarantee Akka is giving to you.

This means that if your `counter` variable is a field in an actor and no other piece of code can access that field directly, you can safely use normal `int`/`long` instead of `AtomicInteger`/`AtomicLong`. Also synchronization on `finalResult` is not necessary assuming it is a field encapsulated and hidden in an actor.

Finally the usage of `CountDownLatch` is suspicious. In Akka applications you shouldn't use any synchronizations primitives. Actors are essentially single-threaded and all communication (including waking up and passing data) should be implemented via message passing.

This is all explained in the documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/general/jmm.html#Actors_and_the_Java_Memory_Model

Comment: Thank you Tomasz. Your first line clears many of my doubts! Regd the usage of the latch, I am having to do that to give a client interface which should wait until the actor processing is completed. My aim is to develop a java framework, which internally would use Akka/Scala to process.

Comment: @sutanudalui: you can call actor *synchronously*, which essentially means Akka will wait for response on some temporary queue. No need to do this manually. Consult Akka docs about `ask` (as opposed to `tell`) message pattern.

Comment: Okay. I'll get a bit more deeper. I have a round robin router with N slave actors. What I intend is to do a parallel processing and then accumulate the result. So the master actor, on receive of each input, routes to one of the slaves. The slaves, on processing the message, messages it back to the master which has to aggregate. This aggregation phase where I was thinking about synchronization issues. From the doc link provided, I see that Akka cannot gurantee (well no one can I guess!) that shared memory, in my case the "finalResult" will be protected. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @sutanudalui: that's the beauty of Akka - even if all slaves finish at the same time, their response messages are queued in master's mailbox and processed one after another. Thus you don't have to bother about synchronization, race conditions, etc.

Comment: Got your point. Will try to review my design. Thanks for all the help!